# How to extract the pixel coordinates of the contour, which is closest to the bottom of the image?

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I am performing some contour analysis on an image:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image=background_removed_ROI, mode=cv2.RETR_TREE, method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

I need to extract the contour, which is closest to the bottom of the image. From the contour, which is closest to the bottom of the image, I then want to extract the coordinates of the pixel, which is closest to the bottom in this contour.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: We can't help you, even if you post original image.

Comment: Iterate through every contour and draw the one with the highest Y coordinate value